# JS How to get discord account data via oauth2

Tags: javascript, json, oauth-2.0, discord

I am developing a moderation bot for discord, I am trying to create a paid plan and therefore I need users to log in with their discord account with oauth2 so that I can fetch user data and know which server has the pay plan, chin. So for now I just created an oauth2 url and set up a redirect for https://bouncerbot.goatcode.it/index.html

then, after the user has logged in, I have this url: https://bouncerbot.goatcode.it/index.html?code=nZauBH6wT0hxn8g8SsS1OwiDvN35nn&guild_id=872213710150713384&permissions=0 so now i want user data (profile picture, username etc) how can i get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely more of an Oauth2 question than a Discord question. This answer will use JS examples using the `node-fetch` library to make web requests, and assumes you're using an `express` backend.

First you want to have the user authorize their account with your client ID and [the `identify` scope](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes). When they click authorize, they'll be sent to your specified redirect URI (`https://example.com/redirect` for this example).

When they're redirected, there will be a `code` GET parameter on the URL they land on, which you should take and send to [Discord's token URL](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant) to get an access token:

```js
app.get('/redirect', async function (req, res) {
    // Check their GET params to get the code
    var code = req.query.code;

    // Make our POST body
    var body = {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': 'https://example.com/redirect',
    };

    // POST that to Discord
    var site = await fetch("https://discord.com/api/v9/oauth2/token", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    });

    // And parse the response
    var response = await site.json();
    var accessToken = response['access_token'];
    res.send(`Access token: ${accessToken}`);
})
```

Using the access token given in Discord's response, you can make a GET request to [get the current user](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user), using an `Authorization` header of `Bearer XXXXX` (where `XXXXX` is your access token):

```js
var site = await fetch("https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
});
var response = await site.json();
var username = response.username;
```

Without knowing more about which libraries you're using I can't specifically give you you'll need for these things, but that's a decent list of examples and which processes you'll need to go through to get the information you want.

Comment: I don't know how to get the access token

Comment: Taking the `code=XXXXX` from your redirect, you need to make a POST request to Discord with that token, your client ID and secret, your scopes, and your redirect URI. The docs give an example in Python: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant-redirect-url-example

Comment: Could you give me an example with javascript?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include examples using `node-fetch` and `express`.

Comment: I tried with your code but I get this error: app is not defined

Comment: I am not using node.js

Comment: You can't do this processing in your browser without exposing your client secret, which you shouldn't do. You will need a backend for this.

Comment: Will i have to use php?

Comment: You can use any backend web processor you like. In Node an example would be Express (as used in my example); Python has Flask, Django, and aiohttp; and yes you could use PHP if you so wanted to - though explaining these goes beyond the scope of the question you asked initially.

Comment: I will try with php. Although I should; or use another hosting, because firebase hosting doesn't support non-static files

Comment: Hello. I'm having trouble logging in discord with php. Can you help me with my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68879995/discord-oauth2-with-php

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar file you can pursue.

```
import { CLIENT_ID, CLINET_SECRET, AUTHORIZATION_URL, REDIRECT_URL } from '../config/keys';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Auth = (props) => {
    const getUserGuilds = async (accessToken) => {
        // console.log(`Guild ${accessToken.data.token_type} ${accessToken.data.access_token}`);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('https://discord.com/api/users/@me/guilds', {
                headers: {
                    authorization: `${accessToken.data.token_type} ${accessToken.data.access_token}`
                }
            });
            // console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    const getUserInfo = async (accessToken) => {
        // console.log(accessToken);
        // console.log(`User ${accessToken.data.token_type} ${accessToken.data.access_token}`);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
                headers: {
                    authorization: `${accessToken.data.token_type} ${accessToken.data.access_token}`
                }
            });
            // console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    const getToken = async (code) => {
        try {
            const options = new URLSearchParams({
                client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret: CLINET_SECRET,
                code,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL,
                scope: 'identify guilds',
            });
            const result = await axios.post('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', options);
            return result;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    const getInfo = async (code) => {
        const accessToken = await getToken(code);
        const userInfo = await getUserInfo(accessToken);
        const guildInfo = await getUserGuilds(accessToken);
        console.log({ userInfo, guildInfo });
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
        // console.log(params);
        if (!params.code) return;
        getInfo(params.code);
    });
    return (
        <div className="Auth">
            <br />
            <a className="btn" href={AUTHORIZATION_URL} >Login with discord</a>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, I most likely want to make a login system and you want to do it with discord, you can check this resource.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSS8VKwwjp0

Comment: I was looking for a similar thing but in the video it is not explained how to get the data of the user who is logged in and in addition he uses EJS which I do not know how to use

Comment: ah, I don't know much about that subject, I suggest you look at some ready-made infrastructures.

Comment: That's right, that's what I'm trying to do but I don't find much online and the discord documentation is not done well

Comment: yes you are right there is no proper documentation or example. I'll get back to you if I can find something to do a little research for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took a while, you can use this:

````
  done(null, user);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
  done(null, obj);
  });
  
  passport.use(new Strategy({
    clientID: "",
    clientSecret: "",
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:8000/callback",
    scope: [ "identify", "guilds" ],
  },
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  process.nextTick(() => done(null, profile));
  }));
  
  app.use(session({
  secret: '123',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  }));
  
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(helmet());
  
  app.locals.domain = process.env.PROJECT_DOMAIN;


app.engine('.ejs', ejs.__express);
app.set('views',__dirname+'/views');
app.use(express.static("public"));

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
extended: true
})); 

function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
req.session.backURL = req.url;
res.redirect("/giris");
}

const renderTemplate = (res, req, template, data = {}) => {
const baseData = {
bot: client,
path: req.path,
user: req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user : null
};
res.render(path.resolve(`${templateDir}${path.sep}${template}`), Object.assign(baseData, data));
};

app.get("/giris", (req, res, next) => {
if (req.session.backURL) {
req.session.backURL = req.session.backURL;
} else if (req.headers.referer) {
const parsed = url.parse(req.headers.referer);
if (parsed.hostname === app.locals.domain) {
req.session.backURL = parsed.path;
}
} else {
req.session.backURL = "/";
}
next();
},
passport.authenticate("discord"));

app.get("/baglanti-hatası", (req, res) => {
renderTemplate(res, req, "autherror.ejs");
});

app.get("/callback", passport.authenticate("discord", { failureRedirect: "/autherror" }), async (req, res) => {
if (req.session.backURL) {
const url = req.session.backURL;
req.session.backURL = null;
res.redirect(url);
} else {
res.redirect("/");
}
});

app.get("/cikis", function(req, res) {
req.session.destroy(() => {
req.logout();
res.redirect("/");
});
});```

You fill in the clientID, clientSecret, callbackURL sections. When the user logs in, it is sufficient to specify the id of any page.
````